# Проблема с копированием объектов в python

Tags: python, python-2.x, список, ссылки

Привет. В цикле генерирую объекты и записываю их в переменную `response`. Указанную переменную добавляю в список. Приведу пример:

```
answer = []
for query in listOfLogs:
    response = {}
    response = Request(query)
    elem = {"response": response, "query": query, 'isNull': False}
    answer.append(elem)
    for item1 in answer:
        print item1
    print "###"
```

В результате, почему-то в списке оказываются ссылки на response и при каждом новом создании объекта `response` функцией `Request` у меня все элементы списка перезаписываются. Хотелось бы, чтобы в список происходило копирование объекта, а не добавление его по ссылке. Приведу пример лога:

```
        Луговая  Рыбачье
###
        Луговая (эксп.) Рыбачье
        Луговая (эксп.) Рыбачье
###
        ЛуговаяРыбачье
        ЛуговаяРыбачье
        ЛуговаяРыбачье
###
     Ногинск, Горьковское шоссе, 56 км, дом 1
     Ногинск, Горьковское шоссе, 56 км, дом 1
     Ногинск, Горьковское шоссе, 56 км, дом 1
     Ногинск, Горьковское шоссе, 56 км, дом 1
###
```

Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: Как работает функция `Request()`? И где расположен список `answer`?

Comment: Какое содержимое у вас в listOfLogs?

Comment: @codename0082016 содержимое тут не важно

Comment: Код в вопросе не может показанный вывод породить ни при каком вводе. Попробуйте создать минимальный но полный  пример кода, который проблему показывает и приведите вывод соответствующий этому коду. [mcve]

Comment: @KitScribe, какая разница, как работает `Request()`? Строки обрабатывает. Историю про `answer` поправил

Comment: @hedgehogues ну мне никакой, а вот если вам важно понять в чём может быть ошибка, то вам должна быть большая. Попробуйте создать минимально воспроизводимый пример, ибо данный код не ломает ссылки

Comment: @KitScribe я разобрался. Внизу ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В питоне многое передаётся по ссылке. Чтобы передавать не по ссылке, нужно явно скопировать объект "специально обученной для этого функцией" `deepcopy` из пакета `copy`:

```
import copy

answer = []
for query in listOfLogs:
    response = {}
    response = Request(query)
    elem = {"response": copy.deepcopy(response), "query": copy.deepcopy(query), 'isNull': False}
    answer.append(elem)
    for item1 in answer:
        print item1
    print "###"
```

Замечу, что в питоне есть две подобные функции: `copy` и `deepcopy`. `deepcopy` делает полное копирование, а `copy` -- поверхностное (не в привычном понимании). Пример их использования и отличия можно найти [здесь](http://evgenqa.blogspot.ru/2014/06/python-copydeepcopy.html)